# Using SUMIFS to add time duration always gives 00:00:00

Tags: vba, excel, xls

```
Sub Add_sumf()
Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Dim cellDate As Integer
cellDate = 0
Dim cellDate1 As Date
cellDate1 = TimeValue("00:00:00")
Dim total    As Integer
total = 0
Dim j As Integer
j = 2
Dim k As Integer
k = 2
Set aa = Workbooks("Book3").Worksheets(1)
Set bb = Workbooks("Final_result").Worksheets(1)
Do While bb.Cells(1, k).Value <> ""

    For Each y In bb.Range("A:A")
    On Error GoTo Label

    If UCase(bb.Cells(j, "A").Value) <> "" Then


     cellDate1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(aa.Range("F:F"), aa.Range("B:B"), UCase(bb.Cells(1, k).Value), aa.Range("G:G"), UCase(bb.Cells(j, "A").Value))                         
    bb.Cells(j, k).Value = TimeValue(cellDate1)

    cellDate1 = TimeValue("00:00:00")
    bb.Cells(j, k).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss"

    On Error GoTo Label

    j = j + 1
    Else
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
    j = 2
    k = k + 1
 Loop
Label:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

I am using above code to add time duration based upon value of two other columns but I always get 00:00:00  as result.

if i use below code i get the answer but its too slow very slow

```
Sub add_it_time()
Dim i As Integer
i = 3
Dim cellDate As Integer
cellDate = 0
Dim cellDate1 As Date
cellDate1 = TimeValue("00:00:00")
Dim total    As Integer
total = 0
Dim j As Integer
j = 2
Dim k As Integer
k = 2
Set aa = Workbooks("Book3").Worksheets(1)
Set bb = Workbooks("Final_result").Worksheets(1)
Do While bb.Cells(1, k).Value <> ""
 'MsgBox bb.Cells(1, k).Value
    For Each y In bb.Range("A:A")
    On Error GoTo Label
   ' MsgBox UCase(bb.Cells(j, "A").Value)
    If UCase(bb.Cells(j, "A").Value) <> "" Then

        For Each x In aa.Range("F:F")
        On Error Resume Next
        If UCase(aa.Cells(i, "B").Value) = UCase(bb.Cells(j, "A").Value) Then
       ' MsgBox aa.Cells(i, "F").Text
       ' total = total + Int(get_Second(aa.Cells(i, "F").Text))
        If UCase(aa.Cells(i, "G").Value) = UCase(bb.Cells(1, k).Value) Then
         'MsgBox aa.Cells(i, "F").Text
        cellDate1 = cellDate1 + TimeValue(aa.Cells(i, "F").Value)
        End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Next
        i = 3
        On Error GoTo Label
         bb.Cells(j, k).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss"
        bb.Cells(j, k).Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(cellDate1, "[hh]:mm:ss")
        total = 0
        cellDate1 = 0
    j = j + 1
    Else
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
    j = 2
    k = k + 1
 Loop
Label:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The source column which contains date is of general formatt
I am new to VBA macros

Comment: Any idea whats wrong in the above code?

Comment: For your "slow" solution you should NOT cycle all cells in column - look towards `UsedRange` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

After discussion in chat with OP it was decided that pure formula solution is fine - below are formulas / actions to do on the **separate** sheet starting `A1`:

1. Row A will be resulting table header: in `A1` I added `Agent Name / Release Code`, and starting `B1` there's a list of all available `Release Code` values (easily got using `Remove Duplicates`).
2. I defined the following named ranges for the simplicity and effectiveness (since initial data is NOT static): `AgentNames=OFFSET('Agent State'!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA('Agent State'!$B:$B)-1,1)` - this will return the range of names on the initial sheet **excluding** the header; `TimeInStateData=OFFSET(AgentNames,0,4)` and `ReleaseCodes=OFFSET(AgentNames,0,5)` as shifted `AgentNames` range.
3. In column `A` we should obtain the list of names, which should be unique, so select in column `A` any number of cells which is **NOT less that number of unique names** - for the sample I used `A2:A51`, and type that formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX(AgentNames,SMALL(IF(MATCH(AgentNames,AgentNames,0)=ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(AgentNames))),MATCH(AgentNames,AgentNames,0),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS(AgentNames))))),"")` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define a **Multicell ARRAY** formula and will result in curly `{}` brackets around it (but do **NOT** type them manually!).
4. `B2`: `=IF(OR($A2="",SUMPRODUCT(--($A2=AgentNames),--(B$1=ReleaseCodes),TIMEVALUE(TimeInStateData))=0),"",SUMPRODUCT(--($A2=AgentNames),--(B$1=ReleaseCodes),TIMEVALUE(TimeInStateData)))` - normal formula, which will return empty value for either empty name or zero time.
5. Copy formula from `B2` to the whole table.

Remarks:

- Resulting range for the sum of time values should be formatted as `Time`.
- If the list of names should be expanded in the future - **repeat step 3 for the new range**, but do NOT drag the formula down - this will result in `You cannot change part of an array` error.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/quudyx1v2fup6sh/AgentsTimeSUM.xls

**INITIAL ANSWER:**

Perhaps that's too simple and obvious, but at a glance I don't understand why you have that line of code:

`cellDate1 = TimeValue("00:00:00")`

right after your `SUMIFS`: `cellDate1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(aa.Range("F:F"), ...`

Try to remove the first one where you assign zeros to `cellDate1`.

Comment: I commented that one .If you see my second code when i use timeValue() and add using for loop it works. Is it that my source has a different format? Actually i have to sum the total breaks taken bay an employee during the day so i have to add duration in column "F" for a particular name in column "A" and a particular break code in column "G"

Comment: @amar It would be nice to see your data sample, or the file as best (at least its relevant part)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oulw9isfks5l71m/Book3.zip?m   dwnload link I have to total Values In "F"  for each value in "G " where name is from "B"

Comment: @amar What is the target range for summarized data?

Comment: I am showing the total in an other sheet which has all names in first column (Unique) And all break codes in first row. I have to show total value at there intersection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25412/discussion-between-peter-l-and-amar)

Comment: Another one brilliant multicell solution. Thanks a lot for the sample file!